# Review Close Votes of a question that looks like test but should be closed

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close

I'm now reviewing close votes and stumbled across a question that for me it should be closed with "Needs details or clarity"

[image: Question to review]

If I go to [the link of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58975097/5675325), can see it has 9 upvotes, one edit from a user with high reputation and two answers (one marked as accepted) with also a good amount of upvotes.

Even though to me this should be closed, previous experience shows me there's high chance this question is just meant as test. Yet, I do think this should be closed as it is.

Could just click "Skip" and move on, but really want to learn how to proceed in such scenarios. What should I do?

Comment: What information would you request from op? For someone like me who has no clue about that language, it looks as if op asks why the operator doesn't behave the same in two examples. Looks like a fine question to me.

Comment: I don't see a question there, so would ask OP «What exactly do you want to achieve?». With the answer to that question, there's high chance the question would become off-topic due to seeking for debug help but needing more information.

Comment: I agree that the question in that question could be a bit more clearly worded, but there is at least the implicit question "why does the operator not behave the same" which is very well answered. This is a question about language behavior/specification, not a debugging question. And even if, there is a very clear MRE.

Comment: Understandable. So, should I just Edit the question and include the question you just mentioned? Because if I vote to close it can be interpreted by the system as a test...

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica if it is clear what the unspoken question is, there is no harm in editing it in yourself.

Comment: Now it is, yes. But before being helped by @BDL it wasn't.

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't vote to close such questions. You can edit the explicite question in if you want, but the question is also fine in it's current state. It is somehow clear what op asks, the question provides all the details needed and is not too broad.

Comment: Rule of thumb: question has Perl/raku as tag -> probably has tons of upvotes despite of not making sense to most

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After being helped by BDL and Gimby, I've decided to click "Edit" to make the question clearer. Turns out it was really a test, as I expected initially, and so got the message

> Congratulations! This was only a test, designed to make sure you were
>   paying attention. You passed. Editing to fix minor problems is always
>   good; Leave Open is also appropriate for questions like this.

[image: Review Close votes]

Comment: Please note that you need domain-specific knowledge to tell if this is a sensible question or just a question asking for code - I can't tell. The appropriate action for those who don't know Perl is to skip the review.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree; the question posed here doesn't actually ask a question *at all*. It doesn't even imply one. I do not need to know Perl to know this is a bad question.

Comment: @TylerH With a minimum of imagination you can add a "why?" at the end of the post. Voilà... a question.

Comment: @Lundin That's OP's job. It's not our place to imagine what OP might be asking about. It just as easily may not be "why".